# Visual customization of a dialog button

Tags: java, android

I am using a dialog in my app that pops up and interacts with the user. I haven't worked with dialogs before, so i know next to nothing about styling them. This is the code:

```
public void openDialog() {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = (LayoutInflater.from(AudioRecorder.this)).inflate(R.layout.audio_name_input, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AudioRecorder.this);
    alertBuilder.setView(view);
    final EditText userInput = view.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());
            if (!inputName.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(AudioRecorder.this, "Next audio clip will be named... " + inputName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                filePathMaking();
            } else {
                inputName = "recorded_audio";
                Toast.makeText(AudioRecorder.this, "Input field empty, next audio clip will be named... " + inputName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });

    Dialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Can we style the "Save" button to display red text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AlertDialog` as *Chrisvin Jem* suggested in his answer but I would like to offer another solution:

You can just create a custom dialog class in order to give your dialog a custom layout, control everything in a separate class - I find it cleaner and more organized.

**For example, create dialogClass:**

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Dialog {

public ProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);

    setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog); //this is your layout for the dialog

    }
}
```

**And all you need to do is to create dialog instant and call it like this:**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressDialog.show(); // this line shows your dialog
```

---

Why I recommend using this and not `AlertDialog.Builder` :

- You can build your layout in a faster way with custom dialog.
- No need to write a lot of code just to add views when you can have a custom layout.
- It's easier (or so I believe) for you to see `myCoolDialog.show();` rather than 50 lines of code or more in a single method.
- Do you need to change anything regarding your dialog look and code? good, go to your separate class and change it instead of adding 20 more code lines to your activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `Button` and then change it's text color. Something along the following lines should work,

```
public void openDialog() {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = (LayoutInflater.from(AudioRecorder.this)).inflate(R.layout.audio_name_input, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AudioRecorder.this);
    alertBuilder.setView(view);
    final EditText userInput = view.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());
            if (!inputName.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(AudioRecorder.this, "Next audio clip will be named... " + inputName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                filePathMaking();
            } else {
                inputName = "recorded_audio";
                Toast.makeText(AudioRecorder.this, "Input field empty, next audio clip will be named... " + inputName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });

    Dialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

    Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    positiveButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0B8B42"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Chrisvin Jem gave the extact answer to your question however if you want more control over your design you can the this code

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourview);

    RelativeLayout submit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
    final EditText edittext = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext);


    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.thanks), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```